# How to create TextInput with validation signs using react native

Tags: react-native

How to create following TextInputs with validation signs using react native

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try implementing Redux-form, https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/

Answer (score 0):

High level idea:

Validation - trigger a async callback in `onSubmitEditing`, validate the result, and get back boolean value

UI - TextInput with some styling (background white + border radius), with an icon positioned relative to the right (-margin)